# Flask pagination, query issue, why so many items?

Tags: flask, pagination, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm workin on a blog page and I'm trying to filter posts by tag, the problem is that I get several pages when only 1 or 2 posts match the query (I have per_page set to 6).

I have another filter by followed posts that works correctly, therefore I guess the problem is in the query object.

This is part of my code for the view index:

```
if current_user.is_authenticated:
        show_followed = bool(request.cookies.get('show_followed', ''))
    if show_followed:
        query = current_user.followed_posts
    elif show_tag:
        tag = Tag.query.filter_by(tag_name=show_tag).first()
        query = tag.post
    else:
        query = Post.query
        
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    pagination = query.order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(
        page, per_page=current_app.config['POSTS_PER_PAGE'],
        error_out=False)
    posts = pagination.items
    
    return render_template("index.html", posts=posts, pagination = pagination, show_followed=show_followed, show_tag=show_tag)
```

when I try to replicate the issue in the console, I check that the query for a sample tag matches 3 posts, nevertheless pagination.total (total items) returns 23! What does the pagination object take as items??

I did this to test in the flask shell:

```
tagname = 'pruebatag'
tag = Tag.query.filter_by(tag_name=tagname).first()
query = tag.post
#here if y try query.all() I get 3 posts in return

pag_object = query.paginate(per_page = 6)

pag_object.total
>>> 23
pag_object.pages
>>> 4

pag_object.items   #returns items for current page
>>> [<Post example>] #only one post returned for this page? why 4 pages?
```

I copy my definition of the tags table:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tags'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    tag_name = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)

    def add_tag(self):
        if not self.id:
            db.session.add(self)
            db.session.commit()

tag_join = db.Table('tag_join',
                    db.Column('post_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('post.id')),
                    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tags.id'))
                    )
```

And in the post model:

```
tags = db.relationship('Tag',
                           secondary=tag_join,
                           backref=db.backref('post', lazy='dynamic'),
                           lazy='dynamic')
```

Any help would be highly appreciated as I am wasting a lot of time on this issue
Just let mi know if you need more details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what happens, I realize that table `tag_join` is full of duplicates, that cause the issue.